# Matlab classes, confusion

Tags: matlab, class

Hey there I'm just learning about classes at the moment.

I don't think my understanding of classes is a 100% to be honest, but I can't get a good grasp on it from the lecture notes. If anyone could give me some hints as to what I am doing wrong it would be well appreciated.

I need to get some that with the input:

```
man = Dumbo('Fred', 10);
fprintf('%s is %d years old.\n', man.name, man.age);
olderMan = man.olderBy(5);  % Get a new older man
fprintf('Older %s is %d years old.\n', ...
  olderMan.name, olderMan.age);
```

To get an output of:

**Fred is 10 years old. 
Older Fred is 15 years old.**

So far I have it working to produce the first line but it is not working for the second, coming up with an error saying:

*Error using Dumbo/olderBy*

*Too many input arguments.*

Here is my code:

```
classdef Dumbo
    %used to find details of a man and an older man

    properties
        name = 'noName'
        age= 0
    end

    methods

        function man=Dumbo(name,age)
            man.name = name;
            man.age = age;
        end

        function olderMan = olderBy(years)
            olderMan.name = man.name
            olderMan.age = man.age + years
        end

    end
end
```

Any suggestions in what I'm wrong, what I could do instead, and reasons behind this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple error.  You forgot to include `man`, or the current object where the method was called from, as an input argument into `olderBy`.  Also, what you're actually doing in the above code is that you are returning a `struct` (thanks @SamRoberts!).  My guess is that you want to return another instance of the object with the fields modified, and so what you should do is create another separate instance of the object.  Once you do that, modify this instance and return this to the user.  That can very simply done by doing `olderMan = man;` at the beginning of your function.

Therefore:

```
function olderMan = olderBy(man,years) %// Change here
    olderMan = man; %// Change
    olderMan.name = man.name
    olderMan.age = man.age + years
end
```

When you're dealing with methods in MATLAB OOP, the first parameter needs to be a reference to the object that the method is being called upon.  In your case, that looks like `man`.  `man` contains a reference to the object that called `olderBy` and this is required for all methods that pertain to `Dumbo`.  I would also recommend that you place semi-colons at the end of each statement in your class.  This way, the output isn't echoed after each statement.... so do:

```
function olderMan = olderBy(man,years) %// Change here
    olderMan.name = man.name;
    olderMan.age = man.age + years;
end
```

Running your code above, I get:

```
Fred is 10 years old.
Older Fred is 15 years old.
```

Comment: Careful @rayryeng. Although your code works to give the output specifically required in the OP's question, `olderMan` is not (which I think might be expected) an object of class `Dumbo`, it's a struct. You might like to put the line `olderMan = man;` before you modify the name and age.

Comment: @SamRoberts very very true. I overlooked that. I'll modify the post when I'm able. Thanks very much for spotting!